# vb debugging textbox changes

Tags: vb.net, debugging

I'm still relatively new to VB and while writing my programs I am tracking textbox changes due to the many calculations I have in my forms.

I have a DIRTY code that tracks changes and if something changes it prompts me to save or ignore.

My question is how do I show what has changed and wants to be updated in the msgbox if "Dirty" fires? There are times when a change is detected by the code but I can see so apparent change. Either that or how do I detect what was changed via the DEBUG? I would be happy even if the textbox changed color  showing a change, at least then I can identify what is supposedly changing.

my DIRTY CODE is as follows:

```
    Private Sub Dirty()
    If Not LoadForm Then
        ' Validate()
        FuelTableBindingSource.EndEdit()
        If Fuel.HasChanges Then
            MeMsgBoxSaveChanges.ShowDialog()
            If MeMsgBoxSaveChanges.Result = "Yes" Then
                NavSaveBtnFuel.PerformClick()
            Else
                Fuel.RejectChanges()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Good information... thank you.. to clarify a bit further - I have many many textboxes on my one form. About 1/3 of these textboxes are populated as the result of a calculation... the user can do nothing in those textboxes. If a record is simply loaded, and is viewed, then moved to another record via the BindingNavigator, Dirty is triggered for some unknown reason and the user then, by default or reaction, saves overwriting whatever was previously saved. No apparent change of any value is noted. This does not happen on all records, but is happening often enough that it becomes a nuisance every time someone wants to view a record. So I am looking to have the MsgBox display what called the Dirty or do this via the debugger (which I am not too familiar with) to decide if 1: a form formatting error exists (going from 3 to 2 decimal places, for example... yes I do use 3 decimal places in most, but not all calc fields) 2: A calculation error (I have code to catch a calc error so this would be something rare) 3: Something else unknown changed. Based on your answer, I would then need to input most every textbox, that does calculations etc. into the dirty command?

Comment: "Dirty" isn't the right word, it is annoying code.  The user always, *always* clicks Yes and will be annoyed about having to do it repeatedly.  What it really means is "I'm not sure how badly my code is going to mess up next, are you sure you want to run it?"  Enough to select No, but that's not going to happen.  There is no bypass for testing your code, we are not going to test it for you.

Comment: I never asked anyone to test my code. I am looking to try and figure it out myself with a little help. Thank you for your less than helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding correctly:  Whenever the user changes something in one of these text boxes, you call `Dirty()` to prompt the user whether to save that or not, yes?

If it really is important to know WHAT was changed and show it in the message box, you have to know which text box's value was changed, what its previous value was, and what its new value is.  If you are prompting the user whether to save changes or not, then I figure that means you are saving these values somewhere...therefore you already have the previous value for each text box.  So it would be a simple enough matter to pass the text box and the new value to `Dirty()`.

Add parameters to your function to accept those values....something like: `Dirty(ByRef thisBox As TextBox, ByVal newVal As String)`.

Then everywhere you make that call, just add those arguments to your call.  If the calls are within your textbox changed events, then your first argument is the textbox whose change event fired, and the value is simply its .text.

That way, in the code in Dirty you can retrieve the previous value from what was saved, and just reference that and the new value for display.

I do see you are using "MeMsgBoxSaveChanges" which must be your own form.  So you'll have to get that information to your form.  Probably the best way is to have properties of the form for those values and then set the values in `Dirty()`.

For example:  The textbox's name that was changed is "Textbox1".  The previous value is "First", and the new value is "Second".

In Textbox1.TextChanged event:

```
Dirty(TextBox1, TextBox1.Text)
```

In Dirty:

```
Dim prev = [get the saved value that corresponds with TextBox1]
Dim newMsgBox = New MeMsgBoxSaveChanges
newMsgBox.box = thisBox
newMsgBox.prev = prev
newMsgBox.cur = newVal
newMsgBox.ShowDialog()
```

And you'll have to modify MeMsgBoxSaveChanges to display that information as you want it.

---

Per the clarification update:

So I guess I was not fully understanding. If Dirty() is your own method then it must be getting called from somewhere. So if you are not sure why, then I suggest 2 ways to go about finding out:  1) work backward by searching for instances of "Dirty()" in your project, and then inspect the code backward from there to see if you can discover why it's getting called.  2) put a stop point at the first line of code when the navigation button is clicked (since you say it is when a user moves to another record) and step through the code until you come to where "Dirty()" is called so you can find out why.  # 2 would probably be the best to start with to give you a clue and then use # 1 to confirm what you find is the case in all calls (assuming there is more than one place it is called).  If you are not too familiar with using the debugger to set stop points and step through code, here is the MSDN articles (navigation on the left) on [getting started](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt243867.aspx).

Comment: Good information... thank you.. to clarify a bit further -

Comment: @JohnEtling - thank you for the clarification.  I have added an update to my answer to provide you with additional help based on the new information.